# No funcionan las rutas de proyecto en laravel solo la raíz

Tags: laravel, php7, localhost

Estaba yo siguiendo unos posts para poder cambiar la ruta de la carpeta pública de mi proyecto Laravel y no tener que acceder asi: *midominio.com/proyecto_laravel/public* si no acceder directo a *midominio.com*. En la mayoría decía que cambiara el index.php y la estructura de las carpetas, cuando finalicé los cambios me di cuenta que solo podía acceder a la ruta raíz y ya no accedía a las demás rutas. Según yo regresé todo como estaba pero ya ni en mi pc funcionan las rutas, solo se muestra la raíz. ¿Porqué ya no se muestran las demás rutas? Mi index.php

```
/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

;/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Nota: cuando corro el servidor de laravel funcionan bien las rutas. El problema es al usar apache

Comment: solo funciona la pagina principal, pero cuando navegas, este te lanza errores en apache?

Comment: Para configurar que no tengas que entrar a public se hace en tu apache, mas no en tu proyecto.

Comment: @tecnobyte Gracias por tu interés, para cualquier ruta que no es la principal me lanza  Error 404, objeto no localizado

Comment: @bypabloc_ Hola, pues según lo que leí, tenía que moverle a mi proyecto y ahora ya no funciona :'(

Comment: intenta con el comando `a2ensite`, ya que asi me paso una vez y vi que se tiene que habilitar los virtual host en apache

Comment: @tecnobyte Tengo otros proyectos de laravel funcionando bien en mi servidor, el mode rewrite parece estar funcionando bien

Answer (score 0):

consegui solucionarlo configurando el servidor, en mi caso indicandole que la raiz esta en public/index.php

Comment: Y como lo hiciste?